# I want to add an ease transition to mouse parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, parallax.js

I've been working on a project. this is a mouse parallax jquery code. At the moment the elements have linear motion. what i'm looking for is after the mouse stops the motion has to continue for like .2 seconds. Can anyone help on this?. I used a parallax.min.js script file for this.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        jParallax: function(opt) {
            var defaults = { moveFactor: 5, targetContainer: '#parallax' },
                o = $.extend(defaults, opt);
            return this.each(function() {
                var background = $(this);
                $(o.targetContainer).on('mousemove', function(e){
                    mouseX = e.pageX;
                    mouseY = e.pageY;
                    windowWidth = $(window).width();
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    percentX = (0-((mouseX/windowWidth)*o.moveFactor) - (o.moveFactor/2)+o.moveFactor)/2;
                    percentY = (0-((mouseY/windowHeight)*o.moveFactor) - (o.moveFactor/2)+o.moveFactor)/2;
                    background[0].style.transform = "translate("+percentX+"%,"+percentY+"%)";
                });
            });
        }                   
    });
}(jQuery));


$('#img1').jParallax({ moveFactor: 5, targetContainer: '#parallax' });

$('#img2').jParallax({ moveFactor: 10, targetContainer: '#parallax' });

$('#img3').jParallax({ moveFactor: 15, targetContainer: '#parallax' });

$('#img4').jParallax({ moveFactor: 20, targetContainer: '#parallax' });

$('.main-nav').jParallax({ moveFactor: 0, targetContainer: '#parallax'});

$('.logo').jParallax({ moveFactor: 0, targetContainer: '#parallax'});

$('.main-banner-text').jParallax({ moveFactor: 0, targetContainer: '#parallax'});

$('.social-icons').jParallax({ moveFactor: 0, targetContainer: '#parallax'});
```

Comment: And how do you expect us to see what the output is without any html, css ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Here's the html and CSS

```
<header id="parallax">
        <div class="loader-slider"></div>
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/img/Logo.png" class="logo" alt="Markelab Logo"></a>
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">About<div></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services<div></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio<div></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Career<div></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact<div></div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

<!-- Parallax Elements -->

        <div>
            <ul id="scene" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;">
                <li class="layer" id="img1" data-relative-input="true" data-depth="0.30"><img src="resources/img/parallax/layer1.png"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="img2" data-relative-input="true" data-depth="0.50"><img src="resources/img/parallax/layer2.png"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="img3" data-relative-input="true" data-depth="0.60"><img src="resources/img/parallax/layer3.png"></li>
                <li class="layer" id="img4" data-relative-input="true" data-depth="0.80"><img src="resources/img/parallax/layer4.png"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

---------------------------CSS---------------------------

```
#parallax {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#scene{
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    user-select: none;  
}

#scene li{
    list-style: none;
}

#scene li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.layer img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#img1{position: absolute; top: 29%; left: 33%; margin-right: 30%;}

#img2{position: absolute; left: 25.1%; top: 41.8%; margin-right: 7%;}

#img3{position: absolute; left: 13.59%; top: 31.44%; margin-right: 10%;}

#img4{position: absolute; left: 29.32%; top: 32.73%; margin-right: 5%;}
```